# 複数のdataframeをfor文で回したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

`df_1, df_2, df_3` とカラムがすべて同じなデータフレームがあるとき、

```
df_1['year'].shape
df_2['year'].shape
df_3['year'].shape
```

上記を `for` 文で回したく、

```
for i in (1,2,3):
    df_(i)['year'].shape
```

のように実現したいのですが、どのようにすれば自動化できますでしょうか？

Comment: 実際に[pandas.DataFrame.shape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html)を実行したいのですか？ それとも何かの例として仮の名前にしたのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

次のコードのように`eval`を使えばできますが、

```py
for i in (1,2,3):
    eval( "df_"+str(i)+"['year'].shape")
```

`eval`は他に方法がないときの最後の手段だと考えます。
次のコードのように書いた方がよいと思います。

```py
for df in [df_1, df_2, df_3]:
    df['year'].shape
```

どうしても番号でデータフレームを指定したいときは、あらかじめリストを作っておけばよいと思います。

```py
df_list = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
for i in (1,2,3):
    (df_list[i-1])['year'].shape
```

kunifさんのコメントにありますが、`df['year'].shape`だけでは意味のないコードです。単なる例だと解釈しました。

Comment: ご丁寧な回答、誠にありがとうございます。
ご提示頂いた方法を使ってみたところ、意図した結果が得られました。ありがとうございます。
また、おっしゃる通り実際はshapeではなく他のメソッドを、使っておりましたが簡略化のため省かせて頂きました。
お忙しい中お答え頂きありがとうございました！